# SQL to Split Rows into Multiple Column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have below table TEST with singe column DATA

```
00001900-01-01Aseopenigaccount-RF  RF-ADIT
00341900-02-01Aseopenigaccount-RASS  RASS-ADIT
00761900-03-01Adminopenigaccount-RASS  OPEN-System
```

I required above column DATA split into below columns 4 columns

```
Code     Date        Description          ShortDesc
0000 1900-01-01 Aseopenigaccount-RF        RF-ADIT
0034 1900-02-01 Aseopenigaccount-RASS      RF-ADIT
0076 1900-03-01 Adminopenigaccount-RASS    RF-ADIT
```

Comment: Did you try something? Like using the functions `LEFT()`, `SUBSTRING()`, `CHARINDEX()` and `REPLACE()`

Comment: For last column Short desc for some values i m getting blank rows.Can you pls let me know any dynamic method in sql to get correct columns

Answer (score 3):

@at9063, welcome to the community. As the comments indicate, you should provide a sample of your solution in your future questions. It would, also, be really helpful to provide any logical assumptions behind your dataset.

The solution is based on the data that you provided as an example. The first two columns can be extracted by taking the first 4 characters and the following 10. The `Description` column would start on your 15th character and would go up until the first space. `ShortDescr` would start from the first space.

```
SELECT LEFT(my_data,4) AS My_Code,
  SUBSTRING(TRIM(my_data),5,10) AS my_date, 
  SUBSTRING(TRIM(my_data),15,CHARINDEX(' ',my_data)-15) AS My_Description,
  SUBSTRING(TRIM(my_data),CHARINDEX(' ',my_data),LEN(TRIM(my_data))+1-CHARINDEX(' ',my_data)) AS my_ShortDesc 
FROM test
```